# voltage drop - operating a solenoid after a logic gate and a LED

Tags: voltage, logic-gates, solenoid

I have started meddling in circuitry, but I lack any sort of formal training.
Subsequently I apologise for my ignorance.
The circuit I have made (on paper) so far has a number of issues, but I want to try to solve them individually instead of just dumping the whole thing here.
It will be an overengineered box with a bunch of switches and every switch on the box needs to be toggled in order for it to unlock.
I have ordered some parts already and I will be measuring out the values as soon as I have them, so I cannot give you the specifics already - unless you guys are ok with part numbers.

TL:DR 
I want to make a box that can open only after all switches are in the ON position.

The switches and the LEDS are needed in the box (because of a pun I will be making) but I fear the logic gates and the LEDS will drop the voltage too much for the solenoid to operate.

Question: How do I make the switches and leds obligatory while still being able to only unlock the box with the solenoid if all switches are ON.

[image: Part of the big circuit]

Not part of the question:
This is part of the full circuit 
(only as illustration, more questions to come later)

[image: Work in progress]

Edit: Thanks for the suggestions and help so far.
I know I have a lot of stuff still wrong in the circuit, but I need to draw it "as is" if I want to understand it, I'll make a whole bunch of annotations on it and revise it a few times before I get to putting it actually together.
And I'll need to do that, as you guys pointed out as well, it won't work.
I know this but I can't show you the problem without having a problem to show :)
So that's where you guys with all your knowledge of components and know how come into play.
I'm already reading up on a lot of material, see picture 3 and whatever I can find on youtube and the internet.
Thanks for helping me out so far!
Box-parts and holes for LEDs are already accounted for :)

The pun in question has the answer: 'switch the lights (1) on and you will see (2)'

(1) Lights being all the LEDS that light up after switching them on.
(2) you will see: the box that will open

[image: the pun in question]

Comment: You should probably start with some very basic circuits if you are just starting out. There are some basics that have been missed here. Your LEDs will never turn on in your first circuit for example. Also, why do you have a switch for the solonoid if it is connected to the output of the AND gate?

Comment: Read more  basics what not to do with CMOS logic , like floating inputs, ignoring ESD and driving more than say 20mA on the output.  You must learn more before making false assumptions.  Then Read Books on CMOS Applications to see how successful designs work. Keep in mind BASIC examples overlook details. like adding caps All you are trying is a big  NAND gate with pull down R's https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/logic-gates-and-inverters/705?k=NAND&k=&pkeyword=NAND&sv=0&pv1989=0&sf=1&FV=3dc0160%2Ca6c0008%2Cffe002c1%2C1140050&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope your circuit isn't homework, because you're getting the whole answer here.  As drawn, it will not work.  First, you need to actively pull the inputs to the AND gate high.  Second, you're activating the solenoid when the output of the AND gate is low (because the solenoid is connected to +5V on its other end).  Finally, you really don't want to drive a solenoid from a logic gate.

In the circuit below, R2 keeps the AND gate input low when the switches are open.  When SW1 is closed, current flows through R1 and D1, lighting it up.  The behavior is the same for SW2, R3, R4 and D2.

When SW1 and SW2 are closed, the output of the AND gate goes high.  Current flows through R6 and D4 and it lights, regardless of the state of SW3 (which I believe is your intent).  If SW3 is then closed, current will flow through R5 and into the base of Q1.  This will turn Q1 on, which will pull current through your solenoid.

D3 is there to save Q1.  When current is removed from the base of Q1 it will turn off suddenly.  If D3 were not there then L1 would resist the change in current by raising the voltage at the collector of Q1 -- for most combinations, it would do so enough to damage Q1.  D3 will conduct when the voltage at the gate of Q1 rises above 5V, limiting the voltage on Q1's collector, and saving it.

Key words that you may want to search on are elementary logic circuits, and transistor relay driver (or transistor solenoid driver, but usually the solenoid being driven is the coil of a relay, so that's what ends up in search terms).

Adjust the values of R1, R3 and R6 depending on your LEDs and your preference.  Choose Q1 to be herky enough to actually drive your solenoid, and choose R5 to actually drive Q1 into saturation (for hobbyist transistors it should flow 1/10 the collector current in saturation).  Or replace Q1 with a logic-level n-channel MOSFET that's rated for the current it'll need to carry, and either omit R5 altogether, or set it to 220\$\Omega\$ if it's a particularly big FET (to save your AND gate's output stage).  Similarly, size D3 according to how much current there will be flowing in the solenoid.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMz0xj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What does "herky" mean? How will the OP know if the transistor is sufficiently "herky" for the solenoid? Some of our contributors are not native English speakers, and when you throw in arcane slang it makes your writing even harder to understand.

Comment: i think that it means powerful .... "herculean" ..... roman god Hercules

Comment: Alrigth, cool! No, it's not for homework, I've been at work for over 5 years now, and I just want to make a nice box with a stupid pun on it :)

I'm getting into the circuitry because of soldering and I needed some new DIY project. I'm getting that I need to read up on a bunch of stuff, which I am doing right now. The biggest problem I have right now is that I don't know all the options for components out there. I was actually looking for something like a thrystor, but for low voltages and couldn't find it. So that's why I turned to you guys.

See edit in original post.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Yes, my bad about slang -- but, how many know what 'arcane' means, eh?  My presumption about actually sizing the transistor was that my answer was already getting long, and that the answer to that question ("How do I select a transistor for a relay?") should be separate.

Comment: @jsotola: it does.  But by starting with "I think" you make Elliot's point that it was a bit too colloquial ('colloquial' is, at least, in the dictionary...).

Comment: What logic series you should use would be another good separate question (if it hasn't already been asked and answered).  My go-to for casual stuff like this is 74HC series logic, or 74AHC (the 'A' pretty much means "faster" -- but then, so does the 'H', so '74AHC' logic means "faster faster CMOS 7400-series equivalent logic").  I'd recommend 74HC (or even 74C) across the board because it'll be better at keeping you out of trouble, but I've noticed that 74HC seems to be starting to taper off in availability from distributors.

Comment: I just noticed that I put my power in reverse in the first picture (facepalm).
Ok, I admit I'm bad, but that was honestly a mistake